# Tensorflow difference between tf.losses.softmax and tf.nn.softmax

Tags: tensorflow

What is the difference between `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` and `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` and when to use which function??

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I last used Tensorflow, but I'm pretty sure the latter is a wrapper for the former.

The `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` simply uses `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` for calculating the loss, while allowing you to use extra features, like class weights, label smoothing etc.

`tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` also adds the loss to the `tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES` collection, so that you don't need to "route" it all the way to the top, but you can simply collect your losses

```
  losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES)
  loss = tf.reduce_sum(reg_losses)
```

I personally liked being able to personalize my loss functions, so I used the "nn" one, but if you are not going to do anything outside the box, use tf.losses.

I also like to use sparse_softmax_cross_entropy, since most often I was working with mutually exclusive classes, and this way I could avoid converting the labels to one hot encoding myself.

The difference is that in `tf.nn.softmax` you need to use one-hot encoding for your labels, while in `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy`, you can use integers to specify what class number the label belongs too, ie. the difference is

```
labels = [
 [0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0],
]
```

vs

```
labels = [2, 0, 1]
```

Finally, if you are not planning on doing much low-level stuff, I recommend you take a look at Keras.

Comment: `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` is actually a wrapper for `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2` per [the API doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy) now.

Comment: @bsplosion Yep, you are right. But since he asked for the non "v2" one, I assume he is using an older version of Tensorflow for some reason.